# Cyclomatic Complexity - Control Flow Graph

Tags: cyclomatic-complexity, control-flow-graph

I am a newbie. Could you please explain what would happen if a control flow graph consists of multiple start and/or stop nodes?

I searched for the answer but was not able to find a proper one

Thank You in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would happen if a control flow graph consists of multiple start and/or stop nodes when calculating Cyclomatic Complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485378/what-would-happen-if-a-control-flow-graph-consists-of-multiple-start-and-or-stop)

Comment: Thank You. It seems to me that this is the answer.