# What would happen if a control flow graph consists of multiple start and/or stop nodes when calculating Cyclomatic Complexity

Tags: cyclomatic-complexity, code-complexity, control-flow-graph

I want to know how will it affect to the Cyclomatic Complexity when having multiple start or stop nodes in a control flow diagram.If you could explain the relationship between Cyclomatic Complexity and Start/Stop nodes it will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   A control flow graph can consist of many starts and stops. But according to McCabe's theory, if it is consist of multiple starts and stops it doesn't satisfy the formula.